# What languages does Google Cloud Speech Automatic Punctuation Support?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have been playing around with Cloud Speech API and noticed that it returns punctuation for English but not for Japanese when enableAutomaticPunctuation is set to true.

Does anybody know What languages does Google Cloud Speech Automatic Punctuation Support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speech-to-Text can provide punctuation in audio transcription text [for 'en-US' language only](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation#speech-enhanced-model-python).

EDIT MAY 2020: Now, Speech-To-Text supports [more languages](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages)

Comment: Note that this answer is now out of date; please [see my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61574211/6952495)

Answer (score 0):

Update: as of May 2020, several languages have punctuation supported, including Japanese. They have a full list of languages they support and features that are supported for each language [listed here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages).